# One click button and print off multiple Access reports

Tags: ms-access, printing, report, ms-access-reports

I'm currently trying to print off multiple reports in MS Access database with a macro. I hope to use this macro in a form and with one click have only one print preview page show up to select a printer and print off all reports.

I've tried to set up two macros with a slight difference. I can print off all of the reports if I set the macro with the following commands;

OpenReport
(I select the report to print)
RunMenuCommand
(Selected PrintObject)
OpenReport
(I select the report to print)
RunMenuCommand
(Selected PrintObject)
Etc
Etc
Etc....

This macro will have a print preview page appear with every report I've added. I want to avoid this.

I also tried the following as well;

OpenReport
(I select the report to print)
OpenReport
(I select the report to print)
RunMenuCommand
(Selected PrintObject)

This macro only prints off the last report and not multiple reports.

As stated before I'm looking to just have the macro print off all the reports with one print preview page.

If this is or isn't possible then please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: If user must select printer, then that will have to be done with each report. VBA code can be used to set default destination printer, print reports, then set default printer back to original.

Comment: You could just create one report that has each of the other reports as sub-reports with page breaks. That way you only have one Preview of the full printout. I think that is the only way to allow the user to select a printer for multiple reports through a Preview and not through a separate Select printer dialog.